# How to have a hotkey for Microsoft edge browser Translator button

Tags: microsoft-edge, hotkeys

Hotkey for Microsoft edge browser translation page button

I want to add a shortcut key (maybe win+alt+q) to my computer to automatically press the reverse translation of the Microsoft edge browser (display the original page)
I use the python keyboard packege to detect the image button and click it, but for some reason, the image cannot be found after a while (maybe the browser slightly modifies the color or pixel of the button), so this method is currently not feasible for me

I also tried to use the python keyboard packegeto simulate the keys alt+many (shift +tab) to reach the position where the button, but this method will be inaccurate because the number of keys currently displayed on the toolbar in the upper right corner of the browser is not stable.

Please let me know if there is any better way to have a keyboard shortcut to show the original page or what kind of keywords should I look for on the web

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your requirement cannot be achieved at the moment, I simply searched and tried a few. And some popular translation extensions can't meet this requirement. I think you'll have to send your suggestion for relevant team.

Please press `Shift + Alt + I` to edit your suggestion and send it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will give feedback to the relevant team